# Hibernate Envers targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have the following class:

```
@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
public class Yard extends ModelObject {

    // Relations
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk1_yard"))
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonView({Views.AdminPortal.class})
    private House house = null;
}
```

And I get the following error

> Could not write JSON: Unable to find com.db.model.main.House with id 7

My understanding was that `targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED` would prevent this error by only auditing the id number. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is incorrect. I believe what you're looking for is:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Yard extends ModelObject {
  @ManyToOne(optional=false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "house_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk1_yard"))
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @JsonView({Views.AdminPortal.class})
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RElationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  private House house = null;
}
```

You'll notice how the `@Audited` annotation with `targetAuditMode` is being used on the association in the entity mapping rather than on the class-mapping.  That attribute has no impact at the class-level.